# Get selected JTree node index in inserted order

Tags: java, swing, indexing, tree, jtree

I implemented a JTree and I need to get the index of a selected node.

Im trying to get the index using this code:

```
    tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            // This code to get selected index of node
            int[] selectionRows = tree.getSelectionRows();
        }
    });
```

But the method getSelectionRows returns differents results depending if some nodes were collpased or expanded. For example:

This is my Tree:

[image]

If I select one node, like picture after, the getSelectionRows return number 4.

[image]

But if some node were collapsed, like picture after, the getSelectionRows return 3.

I need thats always return 4, thats is the number of the index in order of nodes were inserted.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to track insertion order, how about this?

```
public class MyTreeModel extends DefaultTreeModel {
  int nodeNum = 0;
  Map<MutableTreeNode,Integer> nodeOrder = ...;

  public void insertNodeInto(MutableTreeNode newChild, MutableTreeNode parent, int index) {
    nodeOrder.put(newChild, nodeNum++);
    super.insertNodeInto(newChild, parent, index);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, How can I use this map to get the selected node index?

Comment: if you have the selected node, you can do "int index = nodeOrder.get(selectedNode);"

Comment: And this variable selectedNode, Where do I get the value?

Comment: tree.getLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();

Comment: This method insertNodeInto never execute... I create a Jtree like that:
    model = new MyTreeModel(root); tree = new JTree(model);
And insert element like that:
    root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(element))

Comment: So... Maybe try using it?

Comment: I use the map to put this new DefaultMutableTreeNode... I think it works. =)